# Binding a Map<K, V> with K not being String in Java

Tags: java, binding, dictionary

I'm using BetterBeanBindings in a project and it'd be great if I could do a binding over a Map whose key is not a String.

Let's have an example to explain the situation:

```
public class Bean {
    // ...
    private Map<String, AnotherObject> mapOne;
    private Map<SomeObject, AnotherObject> mapTwo;
    // ...

    public Map<String, AnotherObject> getMapOne() {
        return this.mapOne;
    }

    public void setMapOne(Map<String, AnotherObject> mapOne) {
        Map<String, AnotherObject> oldMapOne = this.mapOne;
        this.mapOne = mapOne;
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("mapOne", oldMapOne, mapOne);
    }

    public Map<SomeObject, AnotherObject> getMapTwo() {
        return this.mapTwo;
    }

    public void setMapTwo(Map<SomeObject, AnotherObject> mapTwo) {
        Map<SomeObject, AnotherObject> oldMapTwo = this.mapTwo;
        this.mapTwo = mapTwo;
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("mapTwo", oldMapTwo, mapTwo);
    }

    // ...
}
```

BBB is able to do bindings over maps whose key is a String (<strike>maybe also over numbers if I remember right</strike> not even primal types, which have a standard parsing) allowing this:

```
Bean bean;
// ...
Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE
        bean, BeanProperty.create("mapOne.xxx"),
        whateverBean, whateverProperty);
```

and this would properly bind the result of `bean.getMapOne().get("xxx")` to the given property of the given object in the 5th and 4th parameters, and viceversa.

But, if we try the same with `mapTwo`

```
Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE
        bean, BeanProperty.create("mapTwo.xxx"),
        whateverOtherOrNotBean, whateverOtherOrNotProperty);
```

the binding attemps to resolve `bean.getMapTwo().get("xxx")` since that is what was provided in the definition of the property and `mapTwo` might not be a `String`, returning `null`. This makes sense as the binding doesn't have to know how to convert that `String` from the property into the required object for resolving

Is there an option to do this? There might be some kind of workaround using a converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked a small workaround which doesn't work for every case but is quite general.

The thing is using a `Map<K, V>` which is able to respond to either values of type `K` or `String` having a `Map<String, V>` backing the main map.

StringBackedMap:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public interface StringBackedMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {

    public V get(String key);

    public boolean containsKey(String key);

    public Set<Entry<String, V>> backerEntrySet();

    public Set<String> backerKeySet();

}
```

StringBackedHashMap:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class StringBackedHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements StringBackedMap<K, V> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, V> backerMap;

    public StringBackedHashMap() {
        super();

        init();
    }

    public StringBackedHashMap(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);

        init();
    }

    public StringBackedHashMap(int capacity, float loadFactor) {
        super(capacity, loadFactor);

        init();
    }

    public StringBackedHashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        super(map);

        init();

        putAll(map);
    }

    private void init() {
        this.backerMap = new HashMap<String, V>();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(String key) {
        return this.backerMap.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V value = super.get(key);

        if (value == null) {
            value = this.backerMap.get(key.toString());
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(String key) {
        return this.backerMap.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return super.containsKey(key) || this.backerMap.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> backerKeySet() {
        return this.backerMap.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, V>> backerEntrySet() {
        return this.backerMap.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V oldValue = super.put(key, value);

        this.backerMap.put(key.toString(), value);

        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        super.putAll(map);

        if ((map != null) && (!map.isEmpty())) {
            for (Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                this.backerMap.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        V oldValue = super.remove(key);

        this.backerMap.remove(key.toString());

        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();

        this.backerMap.clear();
    }

}
```